# Changing button image removes skscene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have started my projects as a `Spritekit` game.
I have put a button on top of my `defaultviewcontroller` in storyboard.
I have presented a scene in `viewwilllayoutsubviews`.

```
 if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            self.skView = skView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            println("Width: \(scene.frame.width) andHEight: \(scene.frame.height)")
            scene.gameSceneDelegate = self
            sceneStack.append(scene)
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

After some time I transitioned to a new scene through viewcontroller code:

```
skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

Now the scene changes but the button I had put on view storyboard stays there, on top of the scene.

In second scene I change the UIButton's image like this:

```
self.lockButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unlocked-button"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Now On pressing the button I change the image of button. This surprisingly results in the scene changing back to the previous scene.
As a result on changing the buttons any property it results in popping of my new scene and reverts back to the scene I presented initially.

**SUMMARY:**
In short what I want is a single UIViewController that will have a general HUD present over every scene of my game. As a result I keep changing the scene being presented by the UIViewController, keeping the UIViewController constant. But when I change any property of the buttons, set via storyboard, displayed over the SKScene (image, backgroundImage, Title etc.) it results in the view reverting back to the initial Scene it displayed.

Comment: it would help if you pasted the code for the button

Comment: my bad, the question has been edited to elaborate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue was:
The initial SKScene presented by the UIViewController was being presented in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`
As a result on changing of any property related to my buttons, the `viewWilllayoutSubviews` was being called.
Changed it such that the initial view was created only once.
A stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this, you designed game GUI menus in Storyboard, and then you wish to call SpriteKit game when button is pressed?

If this is the case, you need to add new view controller (with segue or just call presentViewController method). And in that view controller you set up your  SpriteKit in viewDidLoad or viewWillLayoutSubviews method.

So, when you trigger button, button calls this new view controller (via segue or other way), and game will execute as it should.

However, tricky part is to dismiss game. If you just dismiss view controller that holds game, game will actually still play some things in background (in my case, music and effects!!!).
So, in order do exit game, you need to implement this in your quit level\game button:

```
[(NewGameScreenViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Sorry, Objective-C only, hate swift :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: my hud will be constant, no matter what is the scene. So making new UIViewController for every scene felt like a overkill. Instead I thought I can just keep a ViewController and transition between different scenes. Moving to different scenes will definitely solve the problem but that just does not seem much elegant.